# OpenNERO Ubuntu: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Tags: python, c++, boost, clion, boost-python

I am trying to run [OpenNERO](https://github.com/nnrg/opennero) on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS
I had installed all the dependencies mentioned on their [wiki](https://github.com/nnrg/opennero/wiki/BuildingOpenNero) for building it on Linux. My Python version is 2.7.12, boost version is 1.58, jdk is 1.8.

I opened the project in CLion and built it using Cmake, but when running OpenNERO I am getting the following exception.

```
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO
LOG CREATED in /home/vipin/.opennero/nero_log.txt
2018-Nov-05 01:40:59.139053 (M) [scripting] scripting engine initialized
*** Error in `/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000259a750 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fd1566c67e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fd1566cf37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fd1566d353c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x103)[0x7fd1566bc363]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x157a3d)[0x7fd15842ba3d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0(_ZN5boost6python9exec_fileENS0_3strENS0_3api6objectES3_+0xe8)[0x7fd1580be7e8]
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO(_ZN8OpenNero15ScriptingEngine8ExecFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x8a4)[0x6fd514]
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO(_ZN8OpenNero19LogSpecifyReceiversEiPPcRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x5a)[0x6ff0ba]
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO(_ZN8OpenNero12OpenNeroMainEiPPc+0x78)[0x5dc6b8]
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO(main+0x72)[0x5a8822]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd15666f830]
/home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO(_start+0x29)[0x5adcb9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 17305363                           /home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO
009a5000-009a6000 r--p 003a5000 08:06 17305363                           /home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO
009a6000-009b1000 rw-p 003a6000 08:06 17305363                           /home/vipin/Downloads/opennero-master/dist/OpenNERO
009b1000-009bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0254b000-0265d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fd14c000000-7fd14c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd14c021000-7fd150000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd153154000-7fd15342c000 r--p 00000000 08:06 49939922                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fd15342c000-7fd153431000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 49946281                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
..
...
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

When I tried to debug it, the execution broke on the following statement:
`python::exec_file(filename.c_str(), _globals, _globals);`
Can somebody point me in the right direction, how to solve this?
[image]